# How to call table view controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I need to call a second "table view controller" when a custom cell in the first "table view controller" is tapped:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        var controller: TableViewController1 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("demo1") as! TableViewController1
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

    } else {

        var controller: TableViewController2 = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("demo2") as! TableViewController2
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)

    }

}
```

This code is to call a custom "view controller" not a custom "table view controller".

Or do I need to call the "navigation controller" of the "table view controller"?

Comment: So just to clarify your code example, you have 3 `UITableViewControllers`? The first one, which holds the code you are displaying in your question, `TableViewController1`, and `TableViewController2`? And it looks like if the user selects the first cell you show one table, and for all other cells you show a second table? It just sounds like your comments and code contradict each other and needed some clarification :)

Comment: yes thats exactly what i want. Switch to a second tableviewcontroller when a specific cell in the first tableviewcontroller is tapped.

Comment: you could help me with this issue?

Comment: Currently trying to code up an example and test it out for you!

Comment: oh ok great thanks!:)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make sure you select your main `UITableViewController` and embed a navigation controller by going to: Editor>Embedded In Navigation Controller. Then `Ctrl+Drag` from your first `UITableViewController` to the other two, selecting Manual Segue>Show. Make sure you name your segues in your storyboard, for example I use "table1" and "table2." Then you can use the following code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("table1", sender: self)
    } else {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("table1", sender: self)
    }

}
```

Comment: ok thanks for this, but i have still a question: when i perform the segue, i need to call a destination controller, but do i call a navigation controller or its tableviewcontroller ?

Comment: Why do you need to call a destination controller? Are you just trying to pass variables between the controllers?